# Get full version number of Windows SDK Version labelled "(latest installed version)"

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

If I right click on my project and select Properties > Configuration Properties > General, under Windows SDK Version I see the selected version is "10.0 (latest installed version)". I have several 10.0 versions installed on my system so I just want to confirm exactly which one my project is using by checking the full version number. How can I do that?

Comment: I think this is simply up to the developer to know what’s the current SDK.  That of course is 1903.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have several 10.0 versions installed on my system so I just want to confirm exactly which one my project is using by checking the full version number.

I suspect this is entirely up to the developer to know.  The current [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) is **10.0.18362.1**

The current version of the Windows SDK will appear first in the following table.  Due to the continuous releases of a new version of Windows 10 this table will continuously change over time.  In addition, **Visual Studio 2019** and **Visual Studio 2017** is aware of the current release, due to its own continuous updates it receives.  As new versions are released, the following statement will be updated, it currently states the Windows 10 SDK for Windows 10 1903 is the most recent release.

> The Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0) for Windows 10, version 1903 provides the latest headers, libraries, metadata, and tools for building Windows 10 apps.

Additionally, it indicates that Visual Studio can install the current Windows SDK (provided Visual Studio is updated of course).

> Windows 10 development targeting Windows 10, version 1903 (or later) requires Visual Studio 2017 (or later). This SDK will not be discovered by previous versions of Visual Studio.

[image]

Source: [Windows SDK and emulator archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)